# The Shining Food Locker Scene

Tags: plot-explanation, the-shining

In *The Shining*, how did Jack make it out of the food storage locker? Earlier, Wendy locked him in. Delbert Grady is an evil spirit roaming the Overlook Hotel. If Delbert Grady is only an evil spirit, how did Jack Torrence get out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this would be the same as why Lloyd appeared. *Jack opened himself up to the Hotel.* Jack sold his soul to the Hotel for a drink.

"I would give my soul for a drink."

The Hotel gave him Lloyd, Jack bought a drink and the Hotel had his soul. He goes nuts, and since the Hotel has his soul and wills him to kill his wife and child, it helps him by opening the locker.